# OpenLayers plugin for QGIS problem with maps loading

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I am new in GIS. I use QGIS 2.0.1 with OpenLayers plugin downloaded from official repository. When I click to Add OpenStreetMap layer the map is not showing and load process is never ending. What is the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Did you install OpenLayers plugin using the plugin installer? Is your computer behind a proxy?

Comment: I have a problem the plugin Openlayers in QGIS 2.0 because when I try yo add a layer for example Google Physical Layer it generates a windows with the next message: Ha ocurrido un error mientras se ejecutaba el código de Python: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Usuario/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 50, in addLayer self.__plugin.addLayer(self) File "C:\Users\Usuario/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 204, in addLayer layer = OpenlayersLayer(self.iface, self.__coordRSGoogle, self.olLayerTypeRegistry) File "C:

Comment: The error message complains about a proxy port. Try again without a proxy setting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, which was caused by QGIS not being able to connect to a network to access the internet (ie, I needed to route through a proxy server but QGIS 2 did not pick up the default proxy settings). I resolved the issue by going to Settings>Options>Network and adding in the proxy server details and login credentials.

I am not sure if this is the same problem as what you are encountering, but the symptoms sound familiar, so it is worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem on the Windows 64bits version of QGIS 2.0.1. A colleague was able to run the plugin on the 32bits version.

Other solution : using the TMS source via GDAL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I work on Windows 7 64bit. My friend use the same operation system and plugin works correctly. I dont know where is the problem. Openlayers plugin is installed but it is not in the list of others installed plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved in this way:

Go to Setting>Option>Network and deflag the voice "use a proxy for the web" (o something similar, I use Italian version) in the bottom part of form and it work fine.

Byr